# Clickable item with clickable urls in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have custom ListView item with ImageView and TextView. TextView contains HTML string with urls and some regular text. Im my adapter I have code similar to

`tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='http://google.com'>google</a>"));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

and this works great but `onListItemClick` isn't executed when I click on item outside url,  whole item looks like inactive.

When I click on url I want to fire default action form urls and when I click on regular text or on ImageView I want to execute `onListItemClick` is it possible?

Second question, is it possible to start activity using `<a href="...">start some activity</a>`?

Comment: Second question: no, AFAIK it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make an intent form an anchor.

It's ok and recommended that you use `onListItemClick` (it saves you a lot of work), and if you want to open the link in the browser (without using a `webview`) you can use this an intent, this is an example:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,ContentURI.create("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a callback for each of the views that you wish to select. I believe you have three different items: The `Listview` object, which contains a `TextView` and an `ImageView`.

If you would like to have different behavior for each different piece, you need to create a callback for each different piece. You can set a callback in the XML declaration of the view by setting

```
android:onClick="myCallback"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick